# Can't ping my WIN10 laptop from my phone

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, wireless-networking, lan, ping

I am using some sync application to move files from my phone to an external hard drive plugged to my laptop.

I started this with my old laptop with WIN 7 on it and I was doing it for about 2 years. A month ago I bought a new laptop with WIN 10 on it and since than I can't set up a connection between my phone and laptop.

Both running under my WiFi, I do have ping when I try the link laptop to phone but I don't have a ping when I try the link phone to laptop (that's probably why the sync fails).

What can cause such thing?
Thanks.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I am always using IPs for the ping (I don't really care about the hostnames here)

Comment: Your Windows 10 firewall is blocking the pings. To test it out, disable the firewall real quick and see if you can ping it at that time.

Comment: Yep you were right. I used this http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-and-ftp-traffic-in-windows-10-and-server to enable it. Thanks!